# python aiohttp performance: connect performed on the main thread

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I have the following code

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = [
    'http://54.224.27.241',
    'http://54.224.27.241',
    'http://54.224.27.241',
    'http://54.224.27.241',
    'http://54.224.27.241',
]

async def query(urls):
    out = []
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            try:
                async with session.get(url, timeout=5) as resp:
                    text = await resp.text()
                    out.append(resp.status)
            except:
                print('timeout')
    return out


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
out = loop.run_until_complete(query(urls))
loop.close()

print(str(out))
```

The code is much slower than the one that uses a threadpool and keep increasing if you increase the number of urls (lets say 20, 50 etc.)

I have a feeling that when the initial connection establishment is not done in an async way.

(Note that I am connecting here to an non-existing server to deliberately produce a connection timeout).

Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Comment: 1. Your code has syntax errors. 2. aiohttp doesn't use background threads at all.

Comment: 1. Fixed - my bad. 2. Right, I fixed the description. What I mean is async way - when TCP connection is made session.get() should not wait for the remote counterpart for the reply.

Comment: Is this still slower now you removed the `await async ...`?

Comment: `await async ...` async keyword was here by mistake (syntax error).

Comment: Why not? `session.get()` returns a response object with headers available already. What is the point for getting response event without status code?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov the point is 'performance'. Assume that a typical HTTPS connection establishment duration is 100-200ms, multiply that by 100 requests you already waste a lot of time waiting ONLY for connection establishment. Network layer on the other hand has no problem establishing 100 TCP connections at the same time. The problem is at the application layer.

Comment: I totally missed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** I don't promise this code works, as I can't install `aiohttp` atm, but looking at the example in the [docs](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp)

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Notice how they're calling the `aiohttp.ClientSession()` with the `async` keyword. Additionally, I was getting some error in your line `data = await async with session.get(url) as resp:`

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    out = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            data = await fetch(session, url)
            out.append(data)
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have fixed the syntax errors and modified the example to connect to an non-existent server to show that the connection establishment is non in an non-async fashion. With the exact example from the docs - the same results.

Comment: To install aiohttp: pip install aiohttp (or pip3 install aiohttp)